In-browser CSS editor that saves to git repository
Is there any product that can give me the ability edit CSS on a website like I can in firefox/chrome/safari dev tools, but with the ability to save the result to a git repository containing the source code for the site I'm editing?
The dev tools experience I'm talking about is this (from firefox, but I'm open to any browser):

I know that the CSS I'm editing in the browser may not in general correspond exactly to any file in a git repository, since the css may have minified, transformed, etc, but supposing that my git repository does contain the exact CSS code that appears in the browser, is there any way I can "save" these edits?
Note that I want to avoid solutions where I export the whole page or the whole site from my browser after editing the CSS, because my HTML is generated from a template, and I ultimately want to incorporate a relatively small number of changes (would be 2-3 lines of CSS edits in typical changes, out of hundreds of total lines of CSS code across my website) into a git pull request.
I also am not looking for a solution where I add custom CSS or javascript to a third-party website. I'm editing my own site and I want to incorporate the changes back into the source code for my site that all visitors will ultimately see.
